# CakePHP 3 cell_cache configuration

Tags: caching, cakephp-3.0

I have the following code:

```
$cell = $this->cell('Admin/Notifications', ['since' => $user['last_login']], [
    'cache' => ['config' => 'cell_cache', 'key' => 'notifications_' . $user['id']]
]);
echo $cell;
```

That i use to call a cell in CakePHP 3 and cache it at the same time. But it outputs an error:

```
Warning (512): Could not render cell - The "cell_cache" cache configuration does not exist. [CORE\src\View\Cell.php, line 244]
```

What am I missing? I have searched the manual but have not found if i must declare this configuration and where.

Thank you up front for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. In "config/app.php" I have added the following code to the "Cache" adapters:

```
'cell_cache' => [
    'className' => 'File',
    'prefix' => 'myapp_cell_cache_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
    'serialize' => true,
    'duration' => '+10 minutes',
 ],
```

So it was something I have missed to configure, but it is not specified in the docs. I think it should be added.